# How to put several structs continuous into the memory?

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, space

I am implementing a PSO Algorithm. I use this
data structure:

```
typedef struct {
  float x;
  float y;
} C_struct_Class2D;

typedef struct {
  C_struct_Class2D *pos;
  C_struct_Class2D *best_pos;
  C_struct_Class2D *vel;
} C_struct_Particle;

typedef struct { <br>
  C_struct_Particle **particles;
  C_struct_Particle *g;
} C_struct_Swarm;
```

I have to work with C, not with C++. That's why I use structs instread of classes.

Description of the strucs:

There is a Swarm(C_struct_Swarm) which consists of several Particles(**particles) an an optimum Particles(*g). Each Particle has a Position, Best Position and Velocity of Type
"C_struct_Class2D".

In a few methods I allocate memory space for each data and initialize it. But I' like
the whole data structure to be continuous  in the memory. So that all structs are
behind each other in the address space.

The memory should look like:

```
C_struct_Swarm
particles[0]
particles[0]->pos
particles[0]->best_pos
particles[0]->vel
particles[1]
particles[1]->pos
particles[1]->best_pos
particles[1]->vel
...
...
...
...
particles[n]
particles[n]->pos
particles[n]->best_pos
particles[n]->vel
g->pos
g->best_pos
g->vel
```

How can I achieve this?

Regards
sw

Answer (score 2):

**Compose members by value**

Include C_struct_Class2D by value inside C_struct_Particle:

```
typedef struct {
    C_struct_Class2D pos; 
    C_struct_Class2D best_pos; 
    C_struct_Class2D vel; 
} C_struct_Particle;
```

This guarantees the order of those members (pos is before best_pos is before vel).

**Allocate an array of items, instead of an array of pointers to items**

```
typedef struct {
    C_struct_Particle *particles;
    int num_particles;
    C_struct_Particle g;
} C_struct_Swarm;
```

I should note that here, the data pointed to by particles is NOT contiguous with the other members, so what you are asking for is not entirely possible, unless you do something else like set g to always be the first particle, i.e. included in the particles "array".

**Watch out for padding**

If you don't care about padding (and in your code example it looks like you don't), then skip this. Otherwise it's platform/compiler specific. In GCC for example, you can use the [packed attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html):

```
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) my_packed_struct
{
    char c;
    int  i;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in the way you have described. If you want continuous blocks of memory, the only solution (as far as I know) is to use buffers (see my [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623502/structure-and-pointer/14624300#14624300) that might give you an idea how to implement it).

Answer (score 0):

If you use gcc, for static object you could try `__attribute__`... more info here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

iw source code as example